# "Rerrun to get cross-reference right." LaTeX Warning

Tags: errors, compiling, labels, warnings, output

I'm stuck with this warning: "Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right." The compiler is not able to compile my document and I can't move one.

1. Initially the warning referred to some undefined labels, I tried to compare the new .aux files with the previous ones, but I didn't spot any difference.
2. So I decided to "comment %" every reference (at the moment I use references in my document just for figures) and I tried to recompile it. The warning about undefined labels disappeared but the main warning "rerrun" is still there. I tried to recompile more than twice and It doesn't work. As soon as I remove the comment "%" the problem appears again.
3. Then another warning (you can see it just below) for which I decided to substitute `\usepackage{hyperref}` with `\usepackage{bookmark}` appeared (once I've done the substitution, the warning disappeared but the recompiling process didn't work again):

> Package rerunfilecheck Warning:
> File *****.out has changed.
> Rerun to get outlines right
> or use package `bookmark'.

The document is quite large, so give you a working environment where test the code is not easy. I'm using Visual Code as editor, and I can see the compiler log working.
I'll try to give you a similar MWE to mine:

```
    \documentclass[11pt, a4paper,oneside,english,tipotesi=magistrale,numerazioneromana,evenboxes]{toptesi}

    
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %This pack allows to use UTF8 codification for special characters.
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %font enconding
    \usepackage{comment} %This pack allows for multiple-lines comments.
    \usepackage{enumitem} %This pack allows the creation of lists
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage{geometry} %This pack allows to set margins, paper size and so on.
    \usepackage{mathtools} %This pack introduces several powerful math commands that are not provided by basic LaTeX. Mathtools includes amsmath package.
    \usepackage{fancyhdr} %It allows some text formatting like chapter on top of each page.
    \usepackage{etoolbox} 
    \usepackage{array} %It allows tables formatting.
    \usepackage{booktabs} %It allows to control the thickness of horizontal rules by toprule, midrule, bottomrule.
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    
    
    \usepackage{libertinus} %font
    \usepackage{libertinust1math} %mathfont
    \usepackage{microtype} %improves general typographic
    \usepackage{pifont} %allow special symbol like square or circle with shadows
    \usepackage{bbding} %adds more symbols
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \usepackage{tcolorbox}
    \usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
    \usepackage{optidef} %useful to write optimization problems
    \usepackage{scalerel,amssymb} %allows to scale/stretch and shift objects
    \usepackage{gensymb} %Generic symbols for both text and math mode
    \usepackage{cancel} %Place lines through maths formulae
    
    
    \usepackage{titlesec} %allows different title styles
    \usepackage{xcolor} %color extension
    
    
    \usepackage[hypcap=true]{caption} %It allows to be redirected directly to the figure instead of the caption of the figure, when you click an hyperreference in the text.
    \usepackage{bookmark} %allows cross-referencing 
    
    
    
    
    
    %--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    %This code changes the chapter style and makes it fancier
    
    
    \newcommand{\chapnumfont}{%     % define font for chapter number
     \usefont{T1}{pnc}{b}{n}%      % choose New Chancery, bold, normal shape
     \fontsize{100}{110}%          % font size 100pt, baselineskip 100pt
     \selectfont%                  % activate font
    }
    \colorlet{chapnumcol}{gray!75}  % color for chapter number
    
    \titleformat{name=\chapter}[display]
    {\filleft\bfseries}
    {\filleft\chapnumfont\textcolor{chapnumcol}{\thechapter}}
    {-24pt}
    {\Huge}
    
    \titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
    {\filright\bfseries}
    {\filright}
    {-24pt}
    {\Huge}
    
    
    
    
    
    %-----------------------------------------------------------------------%This set another box where put text inside (for assumptions)
    
    
    \definecolor{mycolor}{rgb}{0.122, 0.435, 0.698}
    
    \newtcbox{\mybox}{enhanced,left skip=15pt,
      colframe=mycolor,colback=mycolor!5!white,
      boxrule=0.5pt,arc=4pt,boxsep=0pt,left=6pt,right=6pt,top=5pt,bottom=5pt, hbox, drop fuzzy shadow}
    
    \newlength{\xdescwd}
    \newenvironment{xdesc}[1]
      {\settowidth{\xdescwd}{\textbf{#1:}}%
       \begin{description}[leftmargin=\dimexpr\xdescwd+.5em\relax,
         labelindent=0pt,labelsep=.5em,
         labelwidth=\xdescwd,align=right]\item[#1:]}
      {\end{description}}
    
    \newtcolorbox{longbox}[2][]{before upper={\begin{xdesc}{#2}},after upper={\end{xdesc}}, 
        enhanced, left skip=15pt, drop fuzzy shadow, breakable, colframe=mycolor,colback=mycolor!5!white,
        boxrule=0.5pt, arc=4pt, boxsep=0pt, left=6pt, right=6pt, top=5pt, bottom=5pt, #1}
    
    
    
    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{15pt} %This command increments column spacing in tables.
    
    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    \newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}} %This commands allow to center tables horizontally and vertically.
    \newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
    
    %-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    \numberwithin{equation}{chapter} %This command allows to enumerate formulas or equations according to the section they belong.
    
    %-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------%This command put headers with no upper case and add number section and name
    
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.\ #1}{}}
    \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection.\ #1}}
    \fancyhead[R]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
    \fancyhead[L]{\rightmark}
    
    %---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------This command generates hyperlinks with tables, figures, chapters and sections
    
    \hypersetup{%
        pdfpagemode={UseOutlines},
        bookmarksopen,
        pdfstartview={FitH},
        colorlinks,
        linkcolor={black},
        citecolor={blue},
        urlcolor={blue}
      }
    
      %-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
      \geometry{left=4cm, right=4cm} %This command set margins
    
      %-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
      \addto\captionsenglish{%
      \renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig.}%
      \renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}%
    } 
    
    %This code change the reference Figure x.x in Fig. x.x when we use the command "figurename and ref" to cite a figure within the text
    
    %------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    
    \begin{document}
    \english
    
    
  \chapter(first chapter)
  \section(first section)

   This is the moon buggy example (\figurename~\ref{moonbuggy}).

     \begin{figure}[h] 
            \centering
            \includegraphics[scale=.15]{figures/moonbuggy}
            \caption{Lunar Roving Vehicle (LRV), also called Moon buggy, is an electric vehicle designed to expand astronauts' range of exploration on the low-gravity lunar surface}
            \label{moonbuggy}
        \end{figure}

\chapter{Second Chapter}

This is the second moon buggy example (\figurename~\ref{moonbuggy2}).
    
         \begin{figure}[h] 
                \centering
                \includegraphics[scale=.15]{figures/moonbuggy2}
                \caption{Lunar Roving Vehicle (LRV) second caption}
                \label{moonbuggy2}
            \end{figure}


   Some random text. Some random text. Some random text. Some random text. Some random text. Some random text. Some random text. Some random text. Some random text. Some random text. Some random text (\figurename~\ref{moonbuggy2}).

         \begin{longbox}[width=.8\linewidth]{Assumption 6}
            The thrust direction can be commanded in any direction 
            instantaneously.
         \end{longbox}
        
Some random text. Some random text. Some random text. Some random text. Some random text. Some random text. Some random text. Some random text.

        \end{document}
```

I suspect that the problem is generated by some floating dynamic somehow, and there is something that confuses the referring and compiling process.
Anyway I respect the order into the figure environment, putting `\label` after `\caption` and before the `\end`.

The strange thing is that everything was working fine, but since I've tried to insert a box in one of the chapter with the `\tcolorbox` environment, the warning appeared and since than the document doesn't compile anymore.
I don't know what to do, I've done a ton of research and I haven't found anything useful for my case.
I rely on your better expierence and competence.

I'm in your hands! Thank you.

Comment: look it doesn't help to reask the question with lots of snippets. Without code that allows us to compile and to check if we can reproduce the problem it is quite impossible to help you.  Stop to guess and speculate, concentrate on making an usable example.

Comment: Thanks for your amazing kindness @UlrikeFischer. I've tried to give a more detailed overview about the problem. I can't give you the whole code for obvious reasons. That's why I'm trying to give you all the necessary pieces to get the whole picture without compromise my work.

Comment: You are simply wasting your time with this. I'm very good at debugging, I'm the maintainer of hyperref, bookmark and also  rerunfilecheck, and I don't see a way to solve your problem without spending many hours assembling this to some coherent example (and without garanty to find the reason at all). So do a step back and consider your options.  A site like this here doesn't work well for the type of support you need.

Comment: Ok @UlrikeFischer, I'll try to add a MWE by editing the post, but I'm quite sure that reproduce the problem will be hard. As I said, the whole code was working properly before adding and (then) removing the box that triggered the warnings. That's why it is so strange, the code is actually the same as before, but now it doesn't work as it should.

Comment: well delete all auxiliary files like aux, out etc and try again. Perhaps it disappears then.

Comment: I've just tried, but it seems to not solve the issue. Meanwhile I'll try to work on a MWE. Just one question: I've seen there is a package called `labelschanged`, I don't know If it can help us to spot the problem. Have you ever heard about it? @UlrikeFischer

Comment: I had not heard of `labelschaged` but the comments say it is based on my code, it is basically the same code as I showed you yesterday as a debugging aid for your duplicate question.

Comment: Alright, thank you both. I will update this post from now on.

Comment: You can find in the first post a new MWE. The error seems to appear when I add the `\longbox` environment. I've repeated the process in a backup previously saved, and the addition has triggered the same warnings . @UlrikeFischer

Comment: that doesn't compile without error for me. Show the complete log-file of your example.

Comment: also I don't have the picture, so if it is not relevant remove it.

Comment: `! LaTeX Error: Command \degree already defined`, `! LaTeX Error: File `figures/moonbuggy' not found.`,  `! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tcb/enhanced' `  The pdf is not intended to be usable if you get any error.

Comment: I commented out the gensym package (\degree error) replaced the images with `example-image` and removed the unknown tcolorbox keys, breakable, enhanced and drop fuzzy shadow, then the document runs withoiut error and gives no re-run warning after the first run. I have posted the code below as a community wiki post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper,oneside,english,tipotesi=magistrale,numerazioneromana,evenboxes]{toptesi}

    
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %This pack allows to use UTF8 codification for special characters.
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %font enconding
    \usepackage{comment} %This pack allows for multiple-lines comments.
    \usepackage{enumitem} %This pack allows the creation of lists
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage{geometry} %This pack allows to set margins, paper size and so on.
    \usepackage{mathtools} %This pack introduces several powerful math commands that are not provided by basic LaTeX. Mathtools includes amsmath package.
    \usepackage{fancyhdr} %It allows some text formatting like chapter on top of each page.
    \usepackage{etoolbox} 
    \usepackage{array} %It allows tables formatting.
    \usepackage{booktabs} %It allows to control the thickness of horizontal rules by toprule, midrule, bottomrule.
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    
    
    \usepackage{libertinus} %font
    \usepackage{libertinust1math} %mathfont
    \usepackage{microtype} %improves general typographic
    \usepackage{pifont} %allow special symbol like square or circle with shadows
    \usepackage{bbding} %adds more symbols
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \usepackage{tcolorbox}
    \usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
    \usepackage{optidef} %useful to write optimization problems
    \usepackage{scalerel,amssymb} %allows to scale/stretch and shift objects
%%%%%    \usepackage{gensymb} %Generic symbols for both text and math mode
    \usepackage{cancel} %Place lines through maths formulae
    
    
    \usepackage{titlesec} %allows different title styles
    \usepackage{xcolor} %color extension
    
    
    \usepackage[hypcap=true]{caption} %It allows to be redirected directly to the figure instead of the caption of the figure, when you click an hyperreference in the text.
    \usepackage{bookmark} %allows cross-referencing 
    
    
    
    
    
    %--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    %This code changes the chapter style and makes it fancier
    
    
    \newcommand{\chapnumfont}{%     % define font for chapter number
     \usefont{T1}{pnc}{b}{n}%      % choose New Chancery, bold, normal shape
     \fontsize{100}{110}%          % font size 100pt, baselineskip 100pt
     \selectfont%                  % activate font
    }
    \colorlet{chapnumcol}{gray!75}  % color for chapter number
    
    \titleformat{name=\chapter}[display]
    {\filleft\bfseries}
    {\filleft\chapnumfont\textcolor{chapnumcol}{\thechapter}}
    {-24pt}
    {\Huge}
    
    \titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
    {\filright\bfseries}
    {\filright}
    {-24pt}
    {\Huge}
    
    
    
    
    
    %-----------------------------------------------------------------------%This set another box where put text inside (for assumptions)
    
    
    \definecolor{mycolor}{rgb}{0.122, 0.435, 0.698}
    
    \newtcbox{\mybox}{left skip=15pt,
      colframe=mycolor,colback=mycolor!5!white,
      boxrule=0.5pt,arc=4pt,boxsep=0pt,left=6pt,right=6pt,top=5pt,bottom=5pt, hbox}
    
    \newlength{\xdescwd}
    \newenvironment{xdesc}[1]
      {\settowidth{\xdescwd}{\textbf{#1:}}%
       \begin{description}[leftmargin=\dimexpr\xdescwd+.5em\relax,
         labelindent=0pt,labelsep=.5em,
         labelwidth=\xdescwd,align=right]\item[#1:]}
      {\end{description}}
    
    \newtcolorbox{longbox}[2][]{before upper={\begin{xdesc}{#2}},after upper={\end{xdesc}}, 
        , left skip=15pt,  colframe=mycolor,colback=mycolor!5!white,
        boxrule=0.5pt, arc=4pt, boxsep=0pt, left=6pt, right=6pt, top=5pt, bottom=5pt, #1}
    
    
    
    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{15pt} %This command increments column spacing in tables.
    
    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    \newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}} %This commands allow to center tables horizontally and vertically.
    \newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
    
    %-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    \numberwithin{equation}{chapter} %This command allows to enumerate formulas or equations according to the section they belong.
    
    %-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------%This command put headers with no upper case and add number section and name
    
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.\ #1}{}}
    \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection.\ #1}}
    \fancyhead[R]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
    \fancyhead[L]{\rightmark}
    
    %---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------This command generates hyperlinks with tables, figures, chapters and sections
    
    \hypersetup{%
        pdfpagemode={UseOutlines},
        bookmarksopen,
        pdfstartview={FitH},
        colorlinks,
        linkcolor={black},
        citecolor={blue},
        urlcolor={blue}
      }
    
      %-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
      \geometry{left=4cm, right=4cm} %This command set margins
    
      %-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
      \addto\captionsenglish{%
      \renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig.}%
      \renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}%
    } 
    
    %This code change the reference Figure x.x in Fig. x.x when we use the command "figurename and ref" to cite a figure within the text
    
    %------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    
    \begin{document}
    \english
    
    
  \chapter(first chapter)
  \section(first section)

   This is the moon buggy example (\figurename~\ref{moonbuggy}).

     \begin{figure}[h] 
            \centering
            \includegraphics[scale=.15]{example-image}
            \caption{Lunar Roving Vehicle (LRV), also called Moon buggy, is an electric vehicle designed to expand astronauts' range of exploration on the low-gravity lunar surface}
            \label{moonbuggy}
        \end{figure}

\chapter{Second Chapter}

This is the second moon buggy example (\figurename~\ref{moonbuggy2}).
    
         \begin{figure}[h] 
                \centering
                \includegraphics[scale=.15]{example-image}
                \caption{Lunar Roving Vehicle (LRV) second caption}
                \label{moonbuggy2}
            \end{figure}


   Some random text. Some random text. Some random text. Some random text. Some random text. Some random text. Some random text. Some random text. Some random text. Some random text. Some random text (\figurename~\ref{moonbuggy2}).

         \begin{longbox}[width=.8\linewidth]{Assumption 6}
            The thrust direction can be commanded in any direction 
            instantaneously.
         \end{longbox}
        
Some random text. Some random text. Some random text. Some random text. Some random text. Some random text. Some random text. Some random text.

        \end{document}
```

Comment: error free version of the example. see comments under the question (cw non-answer)

Comment: Thank you so much @DavidCarlisle. The problem has finally disappeared. So there is no way to get back the "drop shadow ecc.." options inside tcb? Moreover, I would like to know why the package `\gensymb` generated the problem, and which package could potentially replace its functions. Thank you again!

Comment: gensymb generated an error that the symbol was already defined (if you get an error _always_ ask about that, the pdf is not intended to be usable after any error)   simply don't load it: you do not need a replacement.  As for `drop shadow`  and the other keys,I have no idea what they were supposed to do, the system gave a warning that they were unknown so I deleted them. If you found some documentation telling you about them it presumably documented what packages you need to load to define them. @Catarella

Comment: I've solved it by adding `[most]` in the `tcolorbox` package to load the appropriate library for advanced style to work out. Thank you for the clarification. @DavidCarlisle